# Js object cache performance

Tags: javascript, performance, object

I read about better performance in js and i understand that if i have something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)
document.images[i].src="blank.gif"
```

So the better way is to cache the object like this:

```
var theimages = document.images
for (i=0;i<theimages.length;i++)
theimages[i].src="blank.gif"
```

My question is if it is only in dom objects or if in regular objects too that is better performance. for example:

```
var obj = {key: {one: 1, two:2, three: 3}};
obj.key.one = 'something';
obj.key.two = 'something';
obj.key.three = 'something';
```

In this example will be better to do this from performance respective?

```
var obj = {key: {one: 1, two:2, three: 3}};
var objKey = obj.key;
objKey.one = 'something';
objKey.two = 'something';
objKey.three = 'something';
```

Comment: Use jsperf.com to test performance differences.

Comment: Yes but i want to understand why if yes or not. thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to do a hash table lookup each time to resolve `obj.key`.

Comment: So you say there is not performance improvment in the second case?

Comment: No, I'm saying there is. In the first case it has to look up `obj.key` 3 times, the second one only has to look it up once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, caching the subobject will probably be faster.

However, for normal objects, the gain will be negligible, because a search in a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is, in average, O(1). In the worst case is O(n), though.

Caching objects is basically useful to avoid traversing the DOM again and again to retrieve them.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Yes, it's a small answer, but that does not make it bad. Of course, feel free to post a more complete answer.